# How to implement jdoodle API to compile and run java programs in Android Studio?

Tags: java

I am creating an android app too write and run java code in an android device using Android studio
we tried using the jdoodle API to compile and run the java code in the app. But whenever we tried to compile the code ye are getting error 400.
Please tell me how can I implement this API so that i can execute a java file.
we are using java language to write the program

Getting error code 400 while executing this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        try {
                            String clientId = "af52e5b3d******c2d81bade***6c055"; //Replace with your client ID
                            String clientSecret = "e868414f******183267d398d578a448c6a1a70bf8be2896ebc******b013bc"; //Replace with your client Secret
                            String script = editText.getText().toString();
                            String language = "java";
                            String versionIndex = "0";
                            URL url = new URL("https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute");
                            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            connection.setDoOutput(true);
                            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            String input = "{\"clientId\": \"" + clientId + "\",\"clientSecret\":\"" + clientSecret + "\",\"script\":\"" + script +
                                    "\",\"language\":\"" + language + "\",\"versionIndex\":\"" + versionIndex + "\"} ";
                            System.out.println(input);
                            OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
                            outputStream.write(input.getBytes());
                            outputStream.flush();
                            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("Please check your inputs : HTTP error code : " + connection.getResponseCode());
                            }
                            BufferedReader bufferedReader;
                            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    (connection.getInputStream())));
                            StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
                            String output1;
                            System.out.println("Output from JDoodle .... \n");
                            while ((output1 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                results.append(output1);
                            }
                            connection.disconnect();
                            output.setText(results);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
```

here we are pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code 400 is a server side error. I means the server didn't understand your request. If I was to take a guess it would have to do with your input string. It does not appear to be written in the normal way variables are sent in post. That being said, a server can be written to accept the variables any way it wants to. But if it is the reason this is how the string should look.

```
name=value&name2=value2
```

You get the idea. Also JDoodle is a pay service. Most pay services will help you, they don't want to lose a client.